# ValueError from simple Numpy comparison

Tags: python, numpy

I encountered a python issue, I tried various ways but I could not fix it. Would you offer me some hint?

```
sp_step = np.linspace(0.0,2.0,41)  ####  bin size is 50 Kpc
for jj in range(len(sp_step) -1):
    if sp > sp_step[jj] and sp <= sp_step[jj+1]:
        stack_num[jj] += 1
        stack[jj] = map(add,stack[jj],flux_inteplt)
```

I define a numpy array called sp_step, what I want to do is use the variable sp to find which segment of the data is in, then I will stack the corresponding data.

But it says

```
if sp > sp_step[jj] and sp <= sp_step[jj+1]:
```

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I googled this error, tried np.logical_and, but not work.

Thanks.

Comment: What is `sp`? Note that searching for this error returns gobs of results. I assume you've read them all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the more common SO numpy questions.  It's the result of some `numpy` test producing multiple values, and then trying to use that in a Python context that expects only one value.

Take a look at this expression (print its result)

```
sp > sp_step[jj] and sp <= sp_step[jj+1]
```

You may need to add some () to ensure that both equality tests are performed before the `&` (`and` is Python's operator that expects scalar booleans).

```
(sp > sp_step[jj]) & (sp <= sp_step[jj+1])
```

To be used with `if` it has to return just one value.

It is best, when testing `numpy` arrays, to use a mask rather than iteration.

```
mask = (sp>sp_step) & (sp <= sp_step)
sp_step[mask] ...
```

Generally it is faster than iterations, but it can require rethinking the problem.   In any case, the `ValueError` is the result of mixing multiple valued `numpy` logical operations with scalar Python ones.

Comment: Sorry to duplicate close this on you, but you did gain a few upvotes while I was looking. Yes, it is a frequently asked question and frequently answered by you. I wish I could find a canonical Q & A for this error.