# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() , How to fix it?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm going to make a scissors paper rock games using tensorflow, so i wanna input an image and the output like 'paper', 'scissors', or 'rock' depend on the image, but i have a problem to do it => The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() , so How to fix it?, so pls n help me

this is mycode

```
import numpy as np
from google.colab import files
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
%matplotlib inline

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():

  # predicting images
  path = fn
  img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150,150))
  imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
  x = image.img_to_array(img)
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

  images = np.vstack([x])
  classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)

  print(fn)
  if classes==0:
    print('paper')
  elif classes==1:
    print('scissors')
  else:
    print('rock')
```

in the end the error like this

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-ca5bd193fb08> in <module>()
     23 
     24   print(fn)
---> 25   if classes==0:
     26     print('paper')
     27   elif classes==1:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

guide me in my beginner guys plss  Thx

Comment: When in doubt, print it! Could you please try to print classes i.e. print(classes)? Now, is it a single value like 1 or 2 or -1 or is it an array like (i.e. list())?

Comment: `
for class in classes:
     if class==0:
        print('paper')
      elif class==1:
        print('scissors')
      else:
        print('rock')

`

Comment: Truth value testing in arrays in `numpy` is a commonly asked question on S/O, check out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647471/the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambigous-when-trying-t
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025855/valueerror-from-simple-numpy-comparison, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous?rq=1

Comment: i just print classes => print(classes) and it shows

    [[0. 1. 0.]]

Comment: it's [[0. 1. 0.]] not [[0, 1, 0]]

Comment: help me guys  @Sowmya and others :)

Comment: Impossible
`
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0. 1. 0.]])

File "<ipython-input-1-92b2326ae6c5>", line 3
    a = np.array([[0. 1. 0.]])
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

Comment: [[0. 1. 0.]] doesn't make sense

Comment: Do I really need to install `google-colab` to run your code?

Comment: I tried installing `google-colab` and now my jupyter is not working (`jupyter kernel seems to have died`). I am sorry. I am out of this.

Comment: @Sowmya maybe you can help me by checking my code here https://github.com/fauzanshobi/rock-paper-scissors/tree/master

Comment: i've just update my code just print(classes) when i print(classes) the output is [[1. 0. 0.]] the output show the location of the inserted image, but does not show the location folder label like 'paper', 'scissors', or 'rock'. the output just like [[1. 0. 0.]], [[0. 1. 0.]], and [[0. 0. 1.]]